# Local help not working in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, msdn

The local help in Visual Studio 2005 never comes back with anything.  Also, if I'm not connected to the Internet, of course I get nothing. When I run dexplore eventually it takes 100% of cpu.  Also, the F1 help doesn't work (of course).  I've repaired both VS 2005, MSDN in other orders.

Any help will be appreciated!

THanks
-tim

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that has always been an issue or just recently?  You may have to uninstall and reinstall VS.  You could work on this problem for hours but this may be your fastest option.

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting in VS to use local help at Tools > Options > Help > Online (at least in VS2008).

Also, you might have a problem with one of the help packages installed. Microsoft has a tool, [Namespace Sharp](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/NamespaceSharp), that will help you check and repair your help system.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Local Help, but it did not appear until I quit VS 2010, and then from Task Manager, performed an "End process tree" on HelpLibAgent.exe. Then all the downloaded local help finally appeared.